# problema en lograr un efecto con javascript html y css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, angular

Tengo un problema en lograr hacer el efecto de esta página: http://capauwels.com/

El efecto de máquina de escribir ya lo conseguí con ayuda de alguien, pero el problema que se me presentó ahora es que no se me ocurre como hacer el efecto de sombreado blanco que aparece cada vez antes de cambiar la palabra.

Estoy trabajando con Angular y Bootstrap, tenìa una idea en hacerlo aplicando 2 clases con ayuda de la directiva `ngClass` de Angular y el paso de propiedades, hasta ahora lo que podido hacer es un sombreado de izquierda a derecha cuando se escribe la palabra, pero lo que quiero hacer es algo idéntico a lo de la página, que cuando se termine de escribir una palabra, se sombree de derecha a izquierda, se borre y se escriba una nueva palabra.

A continuación dejo los códigos de lo que he logrado hasta ahora:

```js
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.css']
})

export class BodyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  
  bandera = true;
  textToShow= "Bienvenido";
  currentText = '';
  interval: any;
  nombre ="Julián Pinto";
  band = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentText = '';
    if (this.bandera) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.currentText += this.textToShow.charAt(this.currentText.length);
        if (this.currentText.length === this.textToShow.length) {
          setTimeout(()=>this.currentText='',250);
        }
      }, 300);
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contenedor-padre{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: orange;

}


#maquina{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: aquamarine;
}

#fila{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border-style: dotted;
}

.sombreado-transparente{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.sombreado-color{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center" id="contenedor-padre">
    <div class="row" id="fila">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="text-center">{{nombre}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <p class="text-center" id="maquina"><span [ngClass]="{'sombreado-transparente': band, 'sombreado-color': !band}"> {{currentText}} </span> </p> 
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: El plugin que usan en la página se llama typer.js [código fuente](http://capauwels.com/js/typer.js). Puedes verlo en acción con su tutorial en [este  pen](https://codepen.io/jasondavis/full/fHdAt/). También te comparto su [documentación oficial](https://steven.codes/typerjs/docs/index.html)

Comment: solo debias dar click derecho sobre la pagina->ver codigo fuente de la pagina y verias las librerias, estilos entre otros que usa.. con ello veras que usa typer.js.... no te mates haciendo algo que ya existe..:https://steven.codes/typerjs/

Comment: Gracias a todos por su respuesta. Cuál sería la forma correcta de agregar el .js en Angular? es decir, ya descargué el Typer.js ahora en que carpeta de angular debo colocar este archivo? tendría que crear una carpeta nueva en Node_Modules y luego modificar el angular.json? o como debería hacerse?